# How do I open sdcard folder in android file explorer?

Tags: android, file, gesture, explorer

You see I am using a real device instead of an AVD and I am not even able to see file names in the `mnt/sdcard` folder. I want to pull a gesture file from the sdcard. It's not an expandable file, so I sent it to my mail directly from the phone. I'd like to be able to directly pull the file and paste it in a raw way. How do I do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the version of android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the neighbouring folders.Now all phones have the sdcard folder under mnt folder.Mine did have sdcard file.which dint open.Cz it had nothing under it.Checked other spots.Found

1.sdcard0
2.sdcard1

GestureBuilder indicated gesture was under

sdcard0/gesture so i checked there and found it.Pulled it to desktop and copied under raw :)